# Floated items with vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, css-float, alignment, vertical-alignment

I don't know why but my floated images `div class="social">...</div>` stopped working properly. My goal: align images vertically, like a column.

Check the design, its easier to understand: [design preview](http://gamemedia.deviantart.com/art/Barber-Shop-PREVIEW-439641025)

They were on the right side of the window/browser screen, with `:hover` effect but now its not working.

Whats wrong with the code?

Heres my [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aq3T7/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="home">

        <div id="nav">
            <div class="container clearfix">
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services">Serviços</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#team">Equipa</a></li>
                        <a href="#" id="logo" alt="Style Euclides"><img src="http://styleeuclides.site50.net/img/logo.png" alt="Logo Style Euclides" width="90px" height="40px"></a> 
                        <li><a href="#space">Espaço</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#gallery">Galeria</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contatos</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

                <div class="social">
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://styleeuclides.site50.net/img/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://styleeuclides.site50.net/img/ins.png" alt="instagram"></a>
                    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://styleeuclides.site50.net/img/twi.png" alt="twitter"></a>          
                        </div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#home .social{ /* SOCIAL ICONS */
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

#home .social a{
    float: right;
    padding: 1px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#home .social a:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#home .social img{
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0; 
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: care to explain what exactly is not working and what browser youve tried it in? i checked your fiddle in newest chrome and it seems to be working fine...

Comment: yeah, looks to be working fine. I'm getting an opacity change on hover.

Comment: The images are not in a "column", thats my goal. They were before, and it was working in all browsers but I dont know what I've done... Check the design below, you'll understand it better

Design preview: http://gamemedia.deviantart.com/art/Barber-Shop-PREVIEW-439641025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/aq3T7/2/)**:
- added top:150px; and width:40px; to the social div, and reomved margin-top of the images.

```
#home .social{ /* SOCIAL ICONS */
float: right;
display: inline-block;
position: fixed;
z-index: 99;
right: 0;
width:40px;
top:150px;
}

#home .social a{
padding: 1px;
opacity: 0.7;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

#home .social a:hover{
opacity: 1.0;
}

#home .social img{
}
```

Comment: Now its working like before (probably even better!). Thanks a lot m8, can you just explain me what I had wrong, im new to HTML/CSS so I want to understand it more

Comment: your images were displayed on one line simply because the div's width just fits to them .. so I added a width to it .. and you gave the margin-top to the images so each one will have a margin-top which is disastrous .. so I added the margin-top to the containing div '.social'.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your fiddle to reflect what I think you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/aq3T7/1/

```
#home .social{ /* SOCIAL ICONS */
float: right;
display: inline-block;
position: fixed;
z-index: 99;
right: 0;
top:150px;
}

#home .social a{
clear:both;
display:block;
padding: 1px;
opacity: 0.7;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}

#home .social a:hover{
opacity: 1.0;
}

#home .social img{
margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Furthermore, I've also removed some unnecessary margins that you had on some elements.
But basically, your A tags are inline elements, and they will naturally display beside one another. 
If you make them block elements, they will take up their own horizontal row (up to the width of their parent). This is the most important and fundamental concept of CSS.

Comment: This works but Karim AG example is working even better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   #home .social{ /* SOCIAL ICONS */
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        right: 0;
    }

    #home .social a{
        float: right;
        padding: 1px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    #home .social a:hover{
        opacity: 1.0;
    }

    #home .social img{

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go mate, sorted it all out for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/aq3T7/

```
#home .social{ /* SOCIAL ICONS */
    position: fixed;
    top: 110px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#home .social a{
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#home .social a:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
}

#home .social img{
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```